# Extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is not adding CSP header

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring MVC (5.0.3) application I have added a class `SecurityConfig` which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");
    }
    
}
```

My expectation is after browsing http://localhost:2020/webapp/ I will see CSP header in browser's developer console (Network tab). But, nothing related to CSP is added into response header.

I have checked by by applying breaking point at line `http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");` and it's hitting one time during context loading.

What's wrong why CSP header is not getting added in response?

**Update: I even tried with `http.headers()`, according to docs this call  without additional methods on it, will add default security headers. But in my case no one default security header is getting added.**

**As requested I have uploaded the minimal, reproducible Example @ Google Drive, [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/158mTst1s8NDyUywf5bf3Ky6LbHq_ZASe/view?usp=sharing) to download**

Comment: Sorry, I can’t reproduce your issue. Could you perhaps provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example ?

Comment: @s7vr Please check update in question for MVCE.

Comment: Hi, are you using for frontend a Single page application framework like Vue.js or Angular, and for the frontend running the server for development that they provided, i just tried in a project of mine with Vue.js, and if a do the request thru the proxy server i do not get the content-security-policy, but if i call directly the tomcat server started by spring boot, the configuration is there, even if i try with postman to call directly the endpoint in backend, i get the content-security-policy

Answer (score 2):

Looked at the mvce and it appears you are not registering the spring security filter chain. Add below in web.xml and it should all work.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: In mvce, after adding this into web.xml everything is working fine but in actual project after adding this I get error `No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available`. After searching a little bit, [from this source](https://www.baeldung.com/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined) I come to know that I have init. a bean into root-context.xml (as I am using ContextLoaderListener into my application), but question why it is not needed in mvce application.

Comment: I want to use spring security only for security headers and not for authentication and authorization purpose. Is that fine?

Comment: Sorry, not the beans but spring security xml file is needed to make this filter work, but mvce application is not having any such file then also it's working why?

Comment: Hello!! I also following the question to seek the help in the same regard. I am also facing the problem As Amogh said, If I use this filer in mvce then headers are getting added but when I add this filter in my application it throws exception as No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available. How to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve no idea. Perhaps you can create a new question with all the details and someone can help you. I’ll update answers if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/headers.html#headers-csp-configure), you must provide a source URL so an attempt to load a script from another source other than what is declared in the script-src directive will be blocked by the user-agent.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: But I dont want to add any other source for scripts other than "self", then why I should specify the url. And also I did not find anything in docs which says "you have to mention trusted URL, specifying only "self" will not work"

Comment: Of course it does not, the doc will show you what you should do with an example but not what you shouldn't do. In this case, even with your "self", they are specifying the source, I'm just pointing this.

Comment: I also checked with `http.headers()`, according to docs this call only `headers()` without additional methods on it, it will add default security headers. But in my case no one default security header is getting added. Check question for mvce.

Comment: Even more FYI i have checked as you said, I have added this line `http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com");` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below format to add contentSecurityPolicy to your api calls. You can explore further here for your spring version(5.0.3) https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/headers.html#headers-csp

Spring(5.5.X) Security does not add Content Security Policy by default, because a reasonable default is impossible to know without context of the application. The web application author must declare the security policy(s) to enforce and/or monitor for the protected resources. Refer 14.2.8. here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-headers-csp

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com; 
        object-src https://trustedplugins.example.com; report-uri /csp-report- 
        endpoint/");
    }
}
```